# Template parameter overloading with a non-typename last arg

Tags: c++

I'm designing an Array class and wanting to have a number of optional components in a specific order for convenience. Here's my desired header setup:

```
class Allocator {};
Allocator DefaultAlloc;

class ArrayIterator {};

template<typename Key, typename Value, typename Iterator, Allocator& alloc = DefaultAlloc>
class Array {};

template<typename Key, typename Value, Allocator& alloc = DefaultAlloc>
class Array : public Array<Key, Value, ArrayIterator, alloc> {};

template<typename Value, Allocator& alloc = DefaultAlloc>
class Array : public Array<std::size_t, Valve, alloc> {};
```

This code won't work, but is there a way to have the same output syntax for class creation? I can't use a parameter pack of types since my last template arg is a non-typename. Is there any way to achieve this with templates or will I have to use unique names for each specialisation?

Comment: Can parameter be deduced from constructor? (C++17 allows [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) or use some `makeArray` prior to that).

Comment: [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) is also a possibility to only has template type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

class Allocator {};
Allocator DefaultAlloc;

class ArrayIterator {};

template<
    typename Value, 
    typename Key = std::size_t, 
    typename Iterator = ArrayIterator, 
    Allocator& alloc = DefaultAlloc>
class Array {};

class ArrayIterator2 {};

Array<int> v;
Array<long, int> v2;
Array<long, int, ArrayIterator2> v3;
```

Just like non-typename parameters, there is no reason typename parameters cannot have default values.

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, I want them in that specific order, thus making explicit defaults not possible since they're not at the end of the arg list.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that. I'll update if I find something.